# Is the OS and kernel different things?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, operating-system

In various docker posts there seems to differentiate between an OS and the kernel.
I always thought these are interchangeable terms.
Is there a difference between a host OS an application is running and the kernel?

Comment: I'd say that the OS includes more than just the kernel.

Comment: For some cases (micro-kernels), the kernel can be a tiny little piece (e.g. less than 64 KiB) that provides little more than low level task switching code. An OS can include many GiB of stuff that a kernel doesn't (GUI, drivers, file system code, documentation, utilities, sound effects, libraries, ...).

Comment: The Kernel is a subset of the OS. The various utilities that are necessary to run a system are consider part of the operating system. The bounds of what constitutes just the operating system outside the kernel is vague. Sadly, this was marked as a duplicate without giving a link to a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, kernel is the centre most part of the OS. Apart from kernel many software utilities are present there to make a complete OS.

But when speaking in loose terms they can be interchanged.